# wget only parent pages using {..}

Tags: curl, wget, recursive, download, web

I have been trying to download specific pages in website.
The site uses common URL to go to next pages like below.

https://example.com/pages/?p=1

https://example.com/pages/?p=2

https://example.com/pages/?p=3 upto 450.

I just want to download those pages and not the hyperlinks that are linked with in the pages (mean not the child pages, just parent file e.g. ?p1 and ?p2 etc).

I have tried using below command, but it is not working.

```
 wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt https://example.com/pages/\?p\=\{1..450\}
```

Is that mean {..} will not work in wget? If not, are there any option in wget that I can use to achive my goal?

Comment: If you don't want to retrieve documents recursively, then why do you use `-r` (_and_ `--recursive`)? You also double up `-np` with `--no-parent` (these are the same option). You additionally have no space between the last option and the URLs, and the `=` is missing after `p` in the URL.

Comment: Oops. Mistakenly I have shared another try that I have used before. Updating...

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for notifying the error. I have updated my script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't escape the `{` or `}`. The shell would not recognize it as a brace expansion if you do. Just use `"https://example.com/pages/?p="{1..450}`  (provided that `wget` understands how to get multiple URLs).

Comment: @Kusalananda Tried that too. Didn't work. However, I highly appreciate your help. Finally I found that solution, while loop did that work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a shell that understand arithmetic ranges in brace expansions (e.g. `bash` and `ksh93` and `zsh`):

```
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt "https://example.com/pages/?p="{1..450}
```

This would be expanded (before `wget` is called) to

```
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt "https://example.com/pages/?p="1 "https://example.com/pages/?p="2 "https://example.com/pages/?p="3 ... "https://example.com/pages/?p="450
```

With `curl`:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt "https://example.com/pages/?p="{1..450}
```

Saving the output into individual files with `curl`:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt -Ooutfile{1..450}.html "https://example.com/pages/?p="{1..450}
```

Comment: Working great. Previously I tried quoting entire URL e.g. "https://example.com/pages/?p={1..450}", after seeing your answer I got to know that I have to put {..} after quoting the URL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @smc Yes, because you need the shell to react to the brace expansion, which it wouldn't if you quoted it.

Answer (score 0):

while loop does the work for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
a=1
while [ $a -lt 450 ]
do
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt https://example.com/pages/\?p\=$a
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a recursive download of 1 depth from " https://example.com/pages "?

The option "-l 1" should set the recursive depth to 1.

source:
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download